# Troubleshoot SNMP communications issues

Tags: snmp, server-communication

What is SNMP? What are the basic SNMP components?
How SNMP Works and How SNMP communication happens? How can I troubleshoot my SNMP communications issues?

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 questions can be answered with a google search of "snmp". This page on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) is a good starting point.

The last question is more interesting, and really depends on what the problem is. The most common issue is connectivity between SNMP agent and management app:

1. Can you ping it? If not, resolve that, google "cannot ping".
2. Does it respond to ANY request? If not, try a packet analyser such as [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) otherwise google "cannot snmpwalk"

Anything else is problem-specific and can probably be googled.

Comment: Ping is a very poor way to determine whether a host provides a service. ICMP can (and often is) enabled or disabled completely independently of other services. That being said, it can form _part_ of your diagnostics because if you _do_ get a ping response then at least you know that the host is up.

Comment: Anyway most of this answer is "Google it" so not very useful.